# Many-to-Many Ajax Forms (Symfony2 Forms)

Tags: symfony

I have a many-to-many relationship in mongodb between Players and Tournaments.

I want to be able to add many Players to a Tournament at once.  This is trivial to do without ajax, but we have a DB of thousands of Players, and so the form select becomes huge.

We want to use ajax for this.  Is it possible to create a single widget (with js) to handle this properly?  If so, any hints on what jquery plugin (or other) to use?

If not, whats the standard strategy to do this?  I suppose I could heavily change the view for this form and use an ajax autocomplete to add one player at a time, and then some more code to delete each player one at a time.  However, I'd really like to have a single widget I can re-use because its so much cleaner and seems much more efficient.

I have been playing with [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2) all day (similar to jQuery Chosen) and I have it working for adding many Players via ajax, but it does not allow me to set the already attached players when I initially load the page, so I won't be able to see who's already in the tournament and would have to retype everyone in.

Thanks for ANY input on this matter!  I can't find anything via Google.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to accomplish this by `$.ajax` after the constructor within the onload function where `//website/jsonItem` is a json-encoded list of all items, and `//website/jsonItemUser` is a json-encoded list of all items attached to user.  I used `//` to keep the `https/http` consistent between calls.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selectitem').select2({
    minimumInputLength:0
    ,multiple: true
    ,ajax: {
      url: "//website/jsonItem"
      ,dataType: 'jsonp'
      ,data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          q: term, // search term
          limit: 20,
          page: page
        };
      }
      ,results: function (data, page) {
        var more = (page * 20) < data.total;
        return {
          results: data.objects, more: more
        };
      }
    }
    ,initSelection: function(element, callback){
      var items=new Array();
      $.ajax({
        url: "//website/jsonItemUser"
      });
      callback(items);
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "//website/jsonItemUser"
    ,dataType: 'jsonp'
    ,success: function(items, status, ob) {
      $('.selectitem').select2('data',items);
    }
  });
});
```