# Custom form type symfony

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic, symfony, symfony-2.1

I need to set up a custom form type in Symfony that uses the choice type as a parent but doesn't actually require choices to be preloaded. As in I want to be able to populate the select with an ajax call and then submit with one of the options from the call without getting `This value is not valid.` errors, presumably because its not one of the preloaded options.

I don't need a custom data transformer as I am doing that through the bundle controller, I just need Symfony not to complain when I submit with an option that wasn't originally on the list. Here is what my custom form type looks like so far:

```
<?php

namespace ISFP\Index\IndexBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class NullEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $defaultOptions = array(
            'em'                => null,
            'class'             => null,
            'property'          => null,
        );

        $options = array_replace($defaultOptions, $options);

        return $options;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'null_entity';
    }
}
```

Comment: No one? I would have thought this a fairly simple question for someone who knew what they were doing..?

Comment: 1.  7 hours is not a very long time to wait before you assume noone can or will help.  2.  You did not actually ask a question.

Comment: Haha lighthart, true, however Im a little pressed for time as Im meant to be delivering this website to the client later tonight..

Comment: As for a question, I think Im asking if you can put an entity in the `->setAllowedValues()` parameter, but not have it actually load the entity when the form is generated. Does that make sense?

Comment: I dealt with some of these issues at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462839/many-to-many-ajax-forms-symfony2-forms/13384784#13384784  without directly answering this question.  I need to think about this some more before giving a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dude look at the `EntityType` it has a parent as a `choice`. But entire display was handle by `ChoiceType`. When I was doing similar things I've started from overload Both `ChoiceType` and `EntityType`. And then set in overloaded Entity the `getParent()` to mine overloaded choice.

Finally In my case I modify the new `choice` and put there my embedded form. It's tricky to do It. And it consumes lot's of time.

But with that approach i don't have any problem with Validation.

Comment: Could you please extend on this answer? Perhaps provide some working code so I could replicate your solution? Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: You're using symfony2.0 or symfony 2.1?