# Symfony2: Two owning sides on many-to-many?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

Let's say I have an `Person` entity and a `ResearchArea` entity. There is a ManyToMany Doctrine relationship between them with simple join table, a `Person` can have multiple `ResearchArea`s and a `ResearchArea` can have multiple `Person`s.

In my database, there are thousands of `Person`s, but only around 10 `ResearchArea`s.

On the `Person` edit form, I want to present a checkbox list for each `ResearchArea`. This is easy in a form builder:

```
->add('researchAreas', 'entity', array(
    'label' => false,
    'class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:ResearchArea',
    'property' => 'title',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
))
```

When submitting the form and binding the request data, this works well and the ManyToMany is handled nicely.

However, when editing a `ResearchArea` entity, I want to also provide a way to manage the `Person`s associated with that area. However, **I can't use the same entity form type as I did above** because there are so many `Person` entities.

Instead what I want is a `collection` form type, where the user can add/remove `Person` entities. I can do this by rendering text fields for each "row" and accept an ID of the person to add.

To support an approach like that, I need to change the relationship from a ManyToMany to a OneToMany -> ManyToOne and make the join table its own entity. But in doing that, then I can no longer use the nice checkboxes on the `Person` form which would only work with a direct ManyToMany.

Am I just making this all too complicated? Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

For a similar use case I simply used the [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html), rendered as a multiselect (multiple => true, expanded => false) and improved with a jquery plugins. This worked quite well, but I didn't have thousands of entities.

```
->add('persons', 'entity', array(
    'label' => false,
    'class' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:Person',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => false,
))
```

I used a jquery plugin (like [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)) to improve the multiselect and make it more user friendly. With chosen you can simply use:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

With a bit of custom css you might be able to style it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this was a consideration, but the idea of loading a multiselect with > 3000 and growing options was not appealing!

Answer (score 0):

I too, would advocate the entity approach, but I used select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) instead.

In [Many-to-Many Ajax Forms (Symfony2 Forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462839/many-to-many-ajax-forms-symfony2-forms/13384784#13384784) I have some fairly detailed implementation examples.

Select2 can support ajax loading and searching, so the 3000 researchers is not a big deal.